# javafx - apply style to a node without affecting its children

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

I wish to disable focus highlighting on a scrollpane, as it looks ugly. I have managed this with the following css:

```
.scroll-pane
{
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
  -fx-focus-color: transparent;
  -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}
```

However, this also applies the effect on all children of the scrollpane, meaning the buttons inside also have no focus highlighting. This is not what I want.

How can I apply the style to the scrollpane only without affecting its children?